# why execve function map private areas?

Tags: c, linux, virtual-memory

I was reading a textbook which describes e `execve` function as:

Suppose that the program running in the current process makes the following call:

`execve("a.out", NULL, NULL);`

the execve function loads and runs the program contained in the executable object file a.out within the current process, effectively replacing the current program with the a.out program. Loading and running
a.out requires the following steps

1. Delete existing user areas
2. Map private areas. Create new area structs for the code, data, bss, and stack
   areas of the new program. All of these new areas are **private copy-on-write** as:

[image]

3. Map shared areas
4. Set the program counter

I am a little bit confused about step 2, so let's say `fork()` forks a child process and let child process run `execve` for a new program, then why `execve` map the child process's new areas as private copy-on-write? the parent process won't share memory with the child process because parent and child process they map to different object, why the child process is afraid that other processes might write sth to affect it?

Comment: Shouldn't the memory-mapped regions for shared libraries also be private?

Comment: In fork, pages are marked "copy-on-write" for [COW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) optimization. If child/parent attempt to write, it gets a copy of the page with write permission. This is a lazy copy to avoid copying everything.

Comment: Are you asking why Linux doesn't make two completely separate programs use the same memory space? The answer is probably because that would crash both programs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, private mapping is as opposed to shared mapping. A writable shared mapping of the file would require write access to the file, and any changes to it would be reflected on disk and in all other shared mappings of the file, including other instances of the same program or library. This is obviously not wanted.

That's for mappings of the executable file/libraries. For things like bss that don't have file backing ("anonymous" maps), you might wonder why a shared mapping can't be used. Indeed it would until the process forks, but if you fork, the shared anonymous mapping would be shared between the parent and child. Sometimes you want to intentionally do that for maps you create yourself with `mmap`, but it does not give the right semantics for global data objects after fork, so it can't be used here.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the diagram, most of those "private copy-on-write" pages are "demand-zero" pages. That's how Linux handles allocation requests; it copy-on-write maps the zero page. So if you just read the page, you see it filled with zeroes, but it doesn't take up real memory at that point. As soon as you need to write to it, it seamlessly makes a new "real" page filled with zeroes and applies your write to it.

For the rest of them, like the `.data` section, it's mapping in the original data from the executable, but you wouldn't want to modify the file on disk because you reassigned a global variable, so again, copy-on-write is used.

Basically, it's not "copying" a real page from the *original* program, it's just a strategy to serve consistently zeroed pages to the program from the OS, and to cheaply provide access to the original executable's data in a way that allows modification if needed.